# How to find all text and his parent inside a DOM element

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom-traversal

I can't find a way to get node siblings that contain only tabs so I can throw them away and get text only and his parents.

```
<html>
<head><title>My page</title></head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="subject">
      <div> divText <span>
        <a> aText </a>
        spanText </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>

    var subject = document.getElementById('subject');

    function printInnerText(ele)
    {
        var childrens = ele.childNodes;

        if (childrens.length > 1)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++)
            {
                printInnerText(childrens[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(ele.innerText);
        }
    }

    printInnerText(subject);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if "#text" contanins textContent (and wholeText) as an `enter` or `tabs` only I need to move to next node.nextSibling. I need to find text only and his parents.

BTW on ie innerText give me only text without tabs, but I have discover that  chrome works different.

Comment: Do you need to get all texts, but removing tabs and new lines?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Is there any reason this simple code don't work for you: `var subject = document.getElementById('subject'); console.log(subject.innerText);`

Comment: This code works, however I need to know the tag element that contain the text: for example - <div> divText, <span> spanText, <a> aText. To clarify this out I need to grab text that belong ONLY for parent tag, so.... as a div I dont need whole div -:divText aText spanText but only divText, the rest belongs to other childrens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive approach for do this (based on your original try) will be to check for [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) equal to type `Node.TEXT_NODE` while you are traversing the descendants, when you found a text, then you can use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to check the existence of a `non-empty` text, in this particular case, you can get the parent and the related text. As shwon on next example:

```js
var subject = document.getElementById('subject');

function clasifyTextByWrapper(ele)
{
    if (ele.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && ele.nodeValue.trim())
        console.log(ele.parentNode.nodeName + " contains text: " + ele.nodeValue.trim());

    ele.childNodes.length && ele.childNodes.forEach(e => clasifyTextByWrapper(e));
}

clasifyTextByWrapper(subject);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="subject">
    <div> divText <span>
      <a> aText </a>
        spanText </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```